# unix - how to escape a backslash

Tags: bash, unix

How do I escape this string within a bash script that is already using an escape `\`?  I'm using backslash for line continuation, however I need to escape it for `\t`
Specifically the last line in here:

```
"$PSQL" -h $HOST          \
        -p $PORT          \
        -U OWNER          \
        -F '$\t\' --no-align   \
        -f test.sql
```

This is on the command line syntax, I'm trying to run within this script:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U foo -F $'\t' --no-align -f test.sql
```

I tried double escapes, but this doesn't work:
`-F '\$\\t\\' --no-align   \`

Comment: $'\t' passes the tab character to psql. It should work. Maybe it needs the '\t' string?

Comment: It should work *if* your shell is bash. If your script starts with `#!/bin/sh`, not bash, on the other hand...

Comment: On the other hand, it needs to be `$'\t'`, not `'$\t\'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To break `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U foo -F $'\t' --no-align -f test.sql` into multiple lines, just add a `\` after each line:

```
psql -h localhost \
     -p 5432 \
     -U foo \
     -F $'\t' --no-align \
     -f test.sql
```

Specifically:

- Do NOT move the `$` inside the single quotes.
- Do NOT add more backslashes for `\t`.
- Do NOT add backslashes for the single quote.

Comment: The need for an explicit bash shebang might also be worth noting.

Comment: ok, i'm still unable to get it to work. The problme I'm having is that i'm also using `$` for my variables. I can tell using `vim` editor that its not escaping this: `-F $'\t' --no-align    \`

Comment: That code needs no escaping. If you escape it, it will not work. Note that it's bash code and only works in bash scripts. It does not work if the script says `#!/bin/sh`, and it does not work if you run `sh yourscript`.

Comment: Ok, this solution works. Thanks guys. The key was `$'\t'`